How to connect to Cellular using TPE-USB4G2US on Windows?
I have a USB Modem from Thinkpenguin that works very well under GNU/Linux. However, it does not seem to function when plugged into Windows (at least not out of the box).
How can I connect to cellular using my USB modem on Windows? My provider is AT&T.
Thank you so much for any help.

It does state there are Windows drivers and it's compatible with v. 7 through 10. What Windows version is in use? Also, they provide both email and phone support at that site -- have you tried either??  BTW -- Workaround: try running Linux in VM, e.g., WSL2 or VirtualBox.
